# More than one handler on .on()

Tags: jquery, handler

I want to use the same event handler for more than one handler, is there a way?

This is my code:

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseover mouseleave", ".ct-symbol", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```

Instead of applying only to ".ct-symbol", I would want it to apply to:

```
".ct-symbol", ".ct-symbol p"
```

Comment: Just use a comma seperated list `".ct-symbol, .ct-symbol p"`

Comment: So change `.ct-symbol` to `.ct-symbol, .ct-symbol p`

Answer (score 0):

You may go like this:

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseover mouseleave", ".ct-symbol, .ct-symbol p", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```

Just put a comma to separate the other selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseover mouseleave",".ct-symbol, .ct-symbol p", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```